# I wrote the word "old" on my passport main page, by mistake. Do I need to get a new passport?

Tags: passports

I wrote the word "old" on my passport main page, thinking it was my old outdated passport. (I looked at the issued date and thought it was the expired date.) The added word doesn't overlap with any passport information. It's on a blank part of the page. However I'm wondering if I should now get a new passport? Will I be denied entry because of that word written in?
Thanks!